# Show only country_id =1 in list (Symfony + Sonata)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

This is my simple listing of the "News" entity

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list): void
{
    $list
        ->filte
        ->add('id')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('createdAt')
        ->add('updatedAt')
        ->add(ListMapper::NAME_ACTIONS, null, [
            'actions' => [
                'show' => [],
                'edit' => [],
                'delete' => []
            ],
        ]);
}
```

The News entity also has a country_id field (I won't show).
I need show only the news with country_id = 1.
How?

Comment: Are you using EasyAdminBundle? If all cases edit your question with more information

Comment: Sorry, I using Sonata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved with [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list)

```
protected function configureQuery(ProxyQueryInterface $query): ProxyQueryInterface
{
    $query = parent::configureQuery($query);

    $rootAlias = current($query->getRootAliases());

    $query->andWhere(
        $query->expr()->eq($rootAlias . '.my_field', ':my_param')
    );
    $query->setParameter('my_param', 'my_value');

    return $query;
}
```

But need made several changes beacuse $query not is a QueryBuilder Object.

```
protected function configureQuery(ProxyQueryInterface $query): ProxyQueryInterface
{

    $query = parent::configureQuery($query);

    $query_qb = $query->getQueryBuilder();
    $rootAlias = current($query->getQueryBuilder()->getRootAliases());

    $query_qb->andWhere(
        $query_qb->expr()->eq($rootAlias . '.idCountry', ':idCountry')
    );
    $query_qb->setParameter('idCountry', $this->security->getUser()->getCountry()->getId());

    return $query;
    
}
```